# Django customized authentication Session bug

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project using a customized authentication build by me, I run into a problem  where users can bypass my login and get into the home page by simply typing the URL
like this: "`127.0.0.1/account/Adam`" , "`127.0.0.1/account/Bob`" , "`127.0.0.1/account/Alice`"
, those people are not registered in the database and yet they receive "welcome Adam", "welcome Bob", "Welcome Alice"
I have been trying different methods from adding a global variable called `Auth = False`, and once a user is found in the database and the password is matched Auth will receive True, this kinda solved my problem but not as expected because once that variable becomes `Auth = True` example:

> if bob is registred in database and login has been successfully made, with same session Bob can type those urls and manipulating the last url parameter and get Welcome sam, Welcom Alfred....

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth
from users.models import Composter
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


class MyView():
    Vuser = None


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'users/home.html')


#def compost_supplier_register(request):
    return render(request, 'users/compost_supplier_register.html')

def composter_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #extracting form data from a POST request and assigning it to variables representing a composter's name, email, password, address, state, city, and zip code.
        composterName = request.POST['Composter_Name']
        composterEmail = request.POST['Composter_Email']
        composterPassword = request.POST['Composter_Password']
        composterConfirmationPassword = request.POST['Composter_Confirmation_Password']
        composterAddress = request.POST['Composter_Address']
        composterState = request.POST['Composter_State']
        composterCity = request.POST['Composter_City']
        composterZipCode = request.POST['Composter_Zip_Code']
        if composterPassword == composterConfirmationPassword:

            #checks if the entred composter name exists in the database
            if Composter.objects.filter(composterName=composterName).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Name is Already taken !')
                return redirect('composter_register')
                
            #checks if the entred composter email exists in the database
            elif Composter.objects.filter(composterEmail = composterEmail).exists():
                messages.info(request,'Email already taken !')
                return redirect('composter_register')
            else:
                #Affect values to composter object instance
                composter = Composter(composterName = composterName ,composterEmail = composterEmail , composterPassword = composterPassword ,composterAddress = composterAddress, composterState = composterState, composterCity = composterCity ,composterZipCode = composterZipCode)
                #Save the composter instance to the database
                composter.save()
                return redirect('composter_register')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Password is not matching !')
            return redirect('composter_register')
    else:
        return render(request, 'users/composter_register.html')

auth = False

def login(request):
    global auth
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['Email']
        password = request.POST['Password']
        try:
            user = Composter.objects.get(composterEmail = email)
            if(user.composterPassword == password):
                auth = True
                if auth == True:
                    return redirect('account', composterName = user.composterName)
            else:
                auth = False
                return redirect('login')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.info(request,'Please enter your username and password to log in')
            return redirect('login')
        
    return render(request, 'users/login.html')

def account(request, composterName):
    global auth
    if auth == False:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'users/account.html', {'composterName':composterName})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Welcome {{composterName}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [ path('', views.home, name='home'),
                path('composter_register/', views.composter_register, name='composter_register'),
                path('compost_supplier_register/', views.compost_supplier_register, name='compost_supplier_register'),
                path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
                path('account/<str:composterName>', views.account, name='account')
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not invent the wheel from scratch, better to use the solution which Django officially provided.
You could use [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator for the protected APIs

If you want to use your own solution then create a new field/column in your User model and use it instead of using the `auth` variable.